# I am getting error message as "No alert is active" when i run the script using Java in Webdriver

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am getting error message as "No alert is active" when i run the script using Java in Webdriver. This is inconsistent behavior, it gives error sometimes and it does not give error. When I didn't this error message, it will fail at some other location.

Note: The script is working perfectly in my machine.

I have changed all the IE 9  settings in the other machine with my machine setting, from then i am getting this error. previous, i use to get the error message as "Modal Dialog Present".

Please find the code i have used below:

```
//Entering data in the Account Information section
driver.findElement(By.name(OR.getProperty("AccName_Id"))).clear();
driver.findElement(By.name(OR.getProperty("AccName_Id"))).
sendKeys(AccName+"_"+Randnum);
driver.findElement(By.name(OR.getProperty("AccDBA_ID"))).sendKeys("Kumar_DBA");
driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("AccTax_ID"))).sendKeys(""+numberToSend);
driver.findElement(By.name(OR.getProperty("AccAddress_ID"))).sendKeys("124 - City  
Cross Roads");
driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("AccZip_ID"))).sendKeys("00501");
new Actions(driver).sendKeys(driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("AccZip_ID"))),   
"").perform();

//Entering data in the Main Contact Information section 
driver.findElement(By.name(OR.getProperty("AccFName_ID"))).sendKeys("Kumara");
driver.findElement(By.name(OR.getProperty("AccMName_ID"))).sendKeys("S");
driver.findElement(By.name(OR.getProperty("AccLName_ID"))).sendKeys("Swamy");
driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("AccOffNo_ID"))).sendKeys("1234567890");
new Actions(driver).sendKeys(driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("AccOffNo_ID"))), 
"").perform();
driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("AccCellNo_ID"))).sendKeys("0123456789");
new 
Actions(driver).sendKeys(driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("AccCellNo_ID"))),  
"").perform();
driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("AccFaxNo_ID"))).sendKeys("1234567890");
new Actions(driver).sendKeys(driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("AccFaxNo_ID"))), 
"").perform();
driver.findElement(By.name(OR.getProperty("AccEmail_ID"))).sendKeys("abc@abc.com")     ;
driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("save_ID"))).click();
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
isAlertPresent();
Thread.sleep(15000);
driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("AccZip_ID"))).sendKeys("79081");
new Actions(driver).sendKeys(driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("AccZip_ID"))), 
"").perform();
Thread.sleep(8000L);
driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("save_ID"))).click();
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
isAlertPresent();
Thread.sleep(30000);
```

Please help me on this issue ASAP. Help will be appreciated deeply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your web driver code fired before the alert renders. My suggest is to put `wait for alert` after click action.

**Try this code:**

```
    //Do some click action to render alert.
    //statement to wait for an alert.
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,
            30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
   //accepting the alert
   driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

The above code will wait for 30 seconds and check the alert presence every 500ms. If the alert is present then it will terminate the wait and do the next action.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will test and let you know the result.

Comment: Thanks Manigandan, it worked for me in the other system. I need to verify the same in my client machine. Thanks once again.